# Bot framework - Getting the user's answers from a form generated by json schema

Tags: c#, json, json.net, botframework, formflow

I am using the function to BuildJsonForm to [define a form using a JSON schema](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/bot-framework/dotnet/bot-builder-dotnet-formflow-json-schema). I generate the JObject with some parameters the bot asks the user during runtime.

An example of the JObject/JSON I send to the function BuildJsonForm is this one:

`

```
  {
    "References": [
      "Microsoft.Bot.Connector.dll",
      "System.dll",
      "mscorlib.dll",
      "System.Net.Http.dll"
    ],
    "Imports": [
      "Microsoft.Bot.Connector.ThumbnailCard",
      "Microsoft.Bot.Connector.StateClient",
      "System.Net.Mail",
      "System",
      "System.Text.RegularExpressions",
      "System.Net.Http",
      "System.Net",
      "System.Text"
    ],
    "type": "object",
    "required": [
      "username",
      "password"
    ],
    "Templates": {
      "NotUnderstood": {
        "Patterns": [
          "I do not understand, Please rephrase that"
        ]
      },
      "EnumSelectOne": {
        "Patterns": [
          "Choose one please"
        ],
        "ChoiceStyle": "Auto"
      }
    },
    "properties": {
      "username": {
        "Prompt": {
          "Patterns": [
            "Tell me the {&}, please",
            "I need you to especify a {&}, please"
          ]
        },
        "type": [
          "string",
          "null"
        ],
        "Templates": {
          "NotUnderstood": {
            "Patterns": [
              "That is not a valid input"
            ]
          }
        }
      },
      "password": {
        "Prompt": {
          "Patterns": [
            "Tell me the {&}, please",
            "I need you to especify a {&}, please"
          ]
        },
        "type": [
          "string",
          "null"
        ],
        "Templates": {
          "NotUnderstood": {
            "Patterns": [
              "That is not a valid input"
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    },
    "OnCompletion": "await context.PostAsync(\"Thank you!\"); string files = \"\"; context.PrivateConversationData.TryGetValue<string>(\"Files\", out files); [more code...]"

}
```

`

I need to send to the database the user's answers to the generated JObject/JSON form's questions, but so far, I haven't found a way to do that.

I also tried accessing the BotData with this line `context.PrivateConversationData.TryGetValue<string>("Files", out files);`, so I could send the user's answers to the database directly from the **"OnCompletion"** section of the JSON, but still I can't seem to access to the botdata or context on the OnCompletion section.

Is there any other way I can successfully retrieve the user's responses to the JObject/JSON generated form after the user answers the last question in the form?

Comment: Perhaps the context is not available here.

Comment: That's what I thought initially but the line in OnCompletion `await context.PostAsync(\"Thank you!\");` (which is also the line you can use to post a bot message in the channel in the Dialog Code) does have context in it. I also tried to access the bot data in onCompletion and got the exception, and now no matter what I do I get that same exception, even with JSONs that have worked perfectly in the past.

Answer (score 0):

It seemed that what was causing the trouble in my project were sending this parameters to the function:

```
GeneratedForm.BuildJsonForm(channel, user, convers);
```

since I edited the function without those parameters and I stopped getting the exception specified in the question. I will look for the reason these parameters were causing problems but the solution I found in this case was to define the funtction this way:

```
GeneratedForm.BuildJsonForm();
```